# Im using Win32_Fan to get and display my Cpu Fan Speed but it's not working why?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

This is the code im calling the method in my Form1 constructor:

```
private void cpuFanSpeed()
        {
            SelectQuery query =
           new SelectQuery("Win32_Fan");

            // Instantiate an object searcher
            // with this query
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

            // Call Get() to retrieve the collection
            // of objects and loop through it
            foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
                MessageBox.Show(envVar["DesiredSpeed"].ToString());
        }
```

But it's never get to the MessageBox.
What is wrong here ? I tried to read and doing it by the document here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394146(v=vs.85).aspx

And here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257359.aspx

But it's not working.

I want to display my cpu fan speed every second on a label.

This is a screenshot of OpenHardwareMonitor display my cpu fan speed:

[image]

And this is the code the function im using in my application to get the CPU temperature:

In class:

```
public static float? cpuView(bool pause , CpuTemperature cpuTemp , Form1 f1 , List<string> myData , float? myCpuTemp , Button b1)
        {
            if (pause == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Computer myComputer = new Computer();
                myComputer = new Computer(cpuTemp)
                {
                    CPUEnabled =

                        true
                };

                myComputer.Open();
                Trace.WriteLine("");
                foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
                {
                    if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                    {
                        hardwareItem.Update();
                        foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardwareItem.SubHardware)
                            subHardware.Update();

                        foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                        {
                            cpuTemp.SetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            {
                                sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                cpuTemp.GetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());                                
                                f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                                myCpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                                if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                {


                                    Logger.Write("The Current CPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                    b1.Enabled = true;
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return myCpuTemp;
        }
```

Comment: are you getting any specific error?

Comment: Arshad no I just can't find out how to get the cpu fan speed with open hardware monitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every machine provides this information through WMI. If your computer doesn't, you won't be able to access it. Just because WMI provides a property to access a particular piece of information doesn't mean that information will always be available.

Presumably, the collection you're iterating through in the `foreach` loop is *empty*, which is why no `MessageBox` ever gets displayed.

The only possible fix for this problem would be to obtain an updated driver from your motherboard manufacturer that provides WMI with this information (assuming, of course, that your hardware even includes the sensors required to measure this type of thing in the first place).

**Edit:** Open Hardware Monitor has apparently written its own drivers to interact directly with your hardware, querying its sensors. This suspicion is confirmed by perusing their web page, which [documents specific pieces of hardware that it supports](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/documentation/).

It's not using WMI to obtain its information, so this doesn't prove that you'll be able to obtain the information from WMI yourself.

However, the bottom of the above-linked page does contain this interesting remark:

> The Open Hardware Monitor publishes all sensor data to WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation). This allows other applications to read and use the sensor information as well. A preliminary documentation of the interface can be found [here](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/OpenHardwareMonitor-WMI.pdf).

So it appears that you can piggyback on top of Open Hardware Monitor, using its drivers to retrieve information, and then retrieve that information from it inside of your app. That's probably the best solution, since I doubt your hardware manufacturer is going to come through with an updated driver that provides the fan speed to WMI.

Comment: Cody I just ran few minutes ago OpenHardwareMonitor and I can see my cpu fan speed. I also used openhardwaremonitor source code in my application to get and display my cpu and video card temperature no problems. But I couldn't find in the openhardwaremonitor source how to get and display my cpu fan speed. Im updating my question .